# Form input data using the lstm for time series problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I have a dataset which contains informations about plants like ID,age, weight, petal color, height, date and time on which the information is taken. Height is the target, so i want to predict height.

Example of my train dataset:

```
|Date | time | ID | color | weight(kilogram) | height(centimeter) | age ( in days) | 
    | ----| -----| -- | ---- -| ---------------- | -------------------| ---------------| 
      15/09/2021| 8pm |14 | yelow | 2 |50|12
      13/04/2021| 8am |3 | pink| 1 |25|10
      13/04/2021| 10pm |3| pink| 1 |30|10
      4/06/2021 | 4pm |5 | green| 2 |50|5
```

We can have information on plants at different times of the day. I would like to predict the size based on several features.

Example of my test dataset:

```
 |Date | time | ID | color | weight(kilogram) | age ( in days) | 
    | ----| -----| -- | ---- -| ---------------- | ---------------| 
      15/09/2021| 8pm |15| yelow | 2 |12
      13/04/2021| 8am |13 | pink| 1 |10
      13/04/2021| 10pm |13| pink| 1 |10
      4/06/2021 | 4pm |55 | green| 2 |5
```

During the prediction we have the same features as in the training without the height (target). I only want to make predictions with my features and not make a complete prediction over a week for example.

I would like to take into account the notion of temporality, i.e. make a prediction of the height according to the past height.

I am having difficulty understanding the input form. Can someone explain to me the form of input data in an lstm with with a dataset of this type?

thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain what the statement "I only want to make predictions with my features and not make a complete prediction over a week for example" means?

Comment: For example, i want give this sequence (15/09/2021| 8pm |15| yelow | 2 |12) to my lstm and it must return to me the high.